# OpenFaces inputTextFilter does not work properly

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, datatable, openfaces

Hi I have `datatable` created using OpenFaces 3.0 this library is great, but I have one problem with it.

I have one column

```
        <o:column header="Symbol" id="symbolCol1"
            sortingExpression="#{p.product.symbol}">
            <f:facet name="subHeader">
                <o:inputTextFilter autoFilterDelay="1000" autocomplete="true"/>
            </f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{p.product.symbol}" rendered="#{p.editable}"
                style="border: 1px solid #CC3333; font-size: 11px;" />
            <h:outputText value="#{p.product.symbol}"
                rendered="#{not p.editable}" />
        </o:column>
```

the problem is that after entering wrong expressions other valid expression does not return any data, only when the page refresh everything back to normal. This table is added to the page by `<o:tabbedPane>` tag. Bean with table data have `@ViewScoped` and master page which include this page using `<ui:include>` also have @ViewScoped scope tag.

Bean getter:

```
public Set<OrderLine> getProdukty() {
if (produkty == null) {
    produkty = produktyP.getProduktyDB();
}
return produkty;
}
```

Comment: OpenFaces 3.0 also seems cool compared to Primefaces 3.0

Comment: This would mean that I have to change the whole xhtml project, it's too much work. I would rather stick with OpenFaces.